# confirmation of method: Write the vector $(2,-3)$ as a linear combination of vectors $(-1,4)$ and $(1,2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Write the vector $(2,-3)$ as a linear combination of vectors $(-1,4)$ and $(1,2)$

this was on an assignment rather hw so I want to be sure I'm using the right method and have the right answer.

I confirm $w = k_1u + k_2v$ to prove I have the right linear combination of vectors.

I solve for $k_1$ and $k_2$

$(-1,4)k_1 + (1,2)k_2 = w$

guassian elimination

$|-1,4 = 2|$

$| 1,2 = -3|$

$=$

$|-1,4 = 2|$

$| 0,6 = -1|$

back substitution

$k_2 = -1/6$

$-1k_1 = 6/3+2/3$

$k_1 = -8/3$

plug $k$'s into vector equation

$(-1,4)(-1/6) + (1,2)(-8/3) = w$

$(1/6,2/3) + (-8/3,-16/3) = w$

$-15/6,-14/3 = w$ .....nope... where did I do it wrong.. and am I using the right method?

Comment: You have switched the $k$s around when you plug them into the original equation.

Comment: $(2,-3) \in \operatorname{span}((-1,4),(1,2))$ because $((-1,4),(1,2))$ is basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$, therefore $\exists! (k_1,k_2) \in \Bbb{R}^2((2,-3)=k_1(-1,4)+k_2(1,2))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be this matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
-1 & 4 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & -3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
since this corresponds to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
-k_1+4k_2 &= 2 \\
k_1+2k_2 &= -3 \\
\end{align*}
whereas you want the system of equations
\begin{align*}
-k_1+k_2 &= 2 \\
4k_1+2k_2 &= -3 \\
\end{align*}
to solve $k_1(-1,4)+k_2(1,2)=(2,-3)$.

So it should instead be
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
-1 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 2 & -3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Aside from that, the method should work fine.

Comment: oh, i dont know how i made that mistake. if I had x,y instead of k1,k2 it would have been more obvious. thanks